identification of old computer used at CERN library
I am trying to identify an old computer, but I cannot find anything like it. There are no labels to indicate the manufacturer. It is likely from the 70's or 80's, and was the first computer to be used in the CERN library. You can find high resolution pictures here: https://cds.cern.ch/record/43945?ln=en
Using image search, the most similar looking computer I could find was the Sol-20, but that one is still very different, in particular the keyboard layout (note the arrow keys in the top-left corner), and the keys on the vertical face.
You can also notice that the layout is of QWERTZ type, which is typical of Switzerland and Germany.


Doesn't look like a computer to me. More like an operators console for an electronic typesetting system - so only part of the terminal to a system. It would help to see connectors (backside) as well as insides.

The inscriptions on the multi-coloured horizontal panel hint very much to a multi-lingual type-setting system. Such systems were often built to order and in very small quantities.

The link does say the 1st computer ever used by cern library. The trouble is, cern is more than capable of building their own systems, then and now, so this may well be a custom build by cern themselves making this question unanswerable. They even invented the internet.

Thanks for your comments! CERN would create its own ICs for a computer, which is also why I was thinking a bit about the Sol-20, since it was also provided as a sort of DIY kit. There are unfortunately no (known) documents left concerning this computer, so it is difficult to say more about its exact functions. I will see if I can acquire some more photos, in particular of the connectors on the back.

@camelccc Small correction: CERN did not invent the internet. What Tim Berners-Lee and his collaborators created at CERN was a networked hyper-text application called "WorldWideWeb" (the earliest forms of HTTP and HTML) which eventually became one of the major uses of the internet. It's like saying "Microsoft invented the personal computer", rather than "Microsoft invented popular software for the personal computer". More relevant is that they were an early connector to the internet, at a time when that required significant technical engineering.

The switches on the upper panel were of a type frequently seen on 'large' computers and their peripherals; I've never seen them on a desktop machine.

@a20 - any evidence for "CERN would create its own ICs for a computer"?  Why on earth would they?

@dave sorry, I meant to say "would NOT". CERN has a lot of in-house production of various things, even simpler PCBs, but I would be surprised if this computer was not bought from somewhere (perhaps as a sort of kit, or perhaps it was modified to some extent), which is why I was hoping someone here might recognize it...

From the Museum of Printing, a Compugraphic CompuWriter IV: https://museumofprinting.org/site/assets/art/compuwriter_IV_x300.jpg  which is a type of Phototypesetter. Not all that similar except for the style of keys and there being a lot of them.

@Brian +1 for mentioning the Museum of Printing. Well worth a visit to anyone at all close. It's a bonus if you can get to talk to Frank Romano.

I worked in printing shops in the '80s and '90s and it looks a lot more DIY than the phototypesetting machines I saw. But the bold and italics keys in the upper left does still lend some credibility to that hypthesis.

There is a 'similar record' in the CERN library : Automatisation of the periodical service at the CERN Library : Preparation and processing computer catalog records ... perhaps this device was used to manage the library catalog card system.

@roblogic amazing! Thank you! That helped me find out exactly what it is. I will write an answer, unless you prefer to do that.

Glad to help! :) Since I can't read French, nor did I actually find the answer, I would be interested to read what you found.

Roblogic linked this document in the comments:
N. Exchaquet, CERN-THESIS-73-001: Automatisation du service des périodiques de la bibliothèque du CERN: Elaboration et traitement en ordinateur des notices catalographiques
which describes the computerization effort at the CERN library in the 1970's. In particular, on page 39 (slide 77 in the pdf), it says:

Le SIS (Scientific Information Service) dispose d'un petit ordinateur PDP 11 pour ses propres besoin. Dans le cadre de
l'automatisation la Bibliothèque bénéficie ainsi d'un instrument
efficace.
The SIS (Scientific Information Service) has a small PDP 11 computer for its own use. As part of its automation program, the library benefits from an efficient instrument.

This led me to the following document from 1975:
A. Van Praag, CERN-75-15: Terminals for the interactive input and editing of bibliographic records on the PDP-11 computer in the CERN library
From its abstract:

As part of the Library Mechanization Project, special computer terminals have been designed and built for the input and display of a wide range of characters, including Greek letters and mathematical symbols. Each terminal consists of a novel 7-bank keyboard together with two Tektronix 611 storage-tube displays, and there are four terminals connected to a PDP-11/20 computer.

The keyboard was connected to the Unibus of the PDP-11 and its design was driven by the "needs for interactive input and editing of bibliographic information in a scientific library". It used an 8-bit coding scheme, to allow for 168 characters, with a switch to allow for another set of 168 characters. The lower part is based on the International typewriter format using ISO 7-bit encoding, while the upper part was used for Greek alphabet and diacritical signs. There were also a number of buttons for various control commands.
The report goes on to explain more details about the terminal, including circuit diagrams in the appendix.


Now that's a real nice find. so as expected a special purpose terminal. Lovely. Thanks.

Very nice. I presume that the library mechanization project of the 1970s ultimately succeeded, as Nicolas Exchaquet evidently went on to a long and respected career in the CERN library, maintaining its electronic catalogues. See: https://www.bge-geneve.ch/sites/default/files/2023-08/rapport-2004.pdf

Compare and contrast:  a) Google for bibliographic software, choose from a selection based on features/price/license, download to your desktop, install, run, use SO for help; or: b) acquire 2 Tek 611s, ~150 key switches w/ caps, another 25 push-buttons w/ lighted caps, 2 metal cases, find your soldering iron and metal nibbler, ... etc etc etc ... all this before writing your own software in assembly language ...  Yet we think we have it rough when the damn software doesn't adjust itself automatically to higher screen resolution ....

Kids today, huh?
